# Struggling with Swift Autolayout and ScrollView Control

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm having serious issues with my attempt to create constraints to align a scrollview control on the bottom of my view based on the distance of a button.

[image: This is my arrangement]

And those are the constraints that I have defined for the scrollview control:

[image: Constraints of scrollview control]

You can see on the preview: The alignment doesn't work in differente devices.

Can someone help me with this?

PS - The content of the ScrollView Control is dynamic and will be loaded programatically.

Comment: You can see red lines around the scroll view; this indicates conflicting or insufficient constraints.  You will also have an error listed in interface builder. In this case I can see you need either a top constraint or a size constraint for your scrollview so that autolayout can determine its size.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollView needs a constraint for either its height or top position. If the height depends on its content, you may add a placeholder constraint in interface builder and change the height constraint at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the y position or height to scroll view.

Or either let the Xcode automatically set the constraints.